# Playing a movie file and then various audio files while movie is playing back. (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to play some audio files while my movie is playing. I don't want it to interrupt or pause he movie. Just the audio to play at same time at various predetermined points.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems with it.

If you want to synchronize or delay these players you should use
the code they provide in [AvAudioPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) using
[playAtTime:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime:) method.

Sadly MPMediaPlayback protocol doesn't provide the same method
so exact synchronizing with video is a bit harder task.

EDIT: RoLYroLLs mentions using `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` to achieve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259608/653513) and this approach seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Use two or three Audioplayer at same time . Play that audio when u need it